# Can I call a method inside of sortWith when sorting a sequence (or a map)?

Tags: scala

I have a map Map[String,Option[Seq[String]]] and I have values for each of the string in a different map: Map[String,Option[Int]]. I am trying to map over the values and use a sortWith on the sequence but as I read online, I don't see any examples of having custom methods inside the sortWith.

How can I sort my sequence using sortWith? If I wanted to implement a custom method that returns a boolean to tell me what object is considered greater, is this possible?

```
val fieldMap = Map("user1" -> Seq("field1_name", "field2_name"), "user2" -> Seq("field3_name"))
val fieldValues = Map("field1_name" -> 2, "field2_name" -> 1, "field3_name" -> 3)

val sortedMap = fieldMap.mapValues(fieldList => fieldList.sortWith(fieldValues(_) < fieldValues(_)) // Scala doesn't like this
```

I tried:

```
fieldList.sortWith{(x,y) => 
    val x = fieldValues(x) 
    val y = fieldValues(y)

    x < y
}
```

This gives me a Type mismatch of expected type:

```
(String,String) => Boolean
```

and actual:

```
(String,String) => Any
```

EDIT Solution:

```
fieldList.sortWith{(x,y) => 
        val x = fieldValues(x) 
        val y = fieldValues(x)

        x.getOrElse[Double](0.0) < y.getOrElse[Double](0.0)  // have to unwrap the Option. 
}
```

Comment: I suspect you meanval y = fieldValues(y) where you have val y = fieldValues(x)

Comment: @ladams yeap, updated post.

Comment: Is there a reason for the Option[Seq[T]]? Why not just keep it as Seq[T] and instead of None, you'd have an empty collection? You could have an empty collection anyway depending on how your object is populated, so you'll have to account for that state already. The option just seems to add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong syntax. For using sortWith you have to do something like:

```
fieldMap.mapValues(
   fieldList => fieldList.sortWith(
     (a,b) => fieldValues(a) > fieldValues(b)
   )
)
```

Comment: I've tried that, edited my post a few seconds before you posted. I'm getting a type mismatch, I forgot to add that the Int is actually a Option[Int].

Comment: What do you min Int is actually a Option[Int]?

Comment: On the second map where I access the Int related to the string field, the map is of type Map[String,Option[Int]], so in some cases, the Int might be Nil.

Comment: adding a .get solved it. Thanks a bunch, your answer helped!